# How to delete searched line and next

Tags: search, cut-copy-paste, global-command

I have a file containing special comments in the following forms:

```
// SPECIAL
// Some stuff
// Some other stuff
// Last line of other stuff
```

So I need to be able to delete the line containing `SPECIAL` and the 3 nexts. Assuming the `SPECIAL` does not appear in the 3 lines after one `SPECIAL`.

I know I can search for `SPECIAL` and then `4dd` but there are a lot in the file so I would prefer to do it automatically.

How to do this?

Comment: Are they all in the same file?

Comment: "I have a file containing..."

Comment: One thing not clear to me. If the number of lines between two `SPECIAL` lines was less than 3, what do you want to do?

Comment: Nice question, but not in my case, let me clarify that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the following command:

```
:g/SPECIAL/.,.+3d
```

Which can be detailled like this:

```
:g/      Apply a command on all the lines matching a pattern
SPECIAL/ The pattern to match
.,.+3d   The command to execute
.,.+3    Is a range. "." represent the current line (i.e. the matched one
         It is updated each time a line is matched
         The full range says "apply the command on the current line and the 3 following"
     d   Is the delete function
```

See [`:h :d`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:d)

---

**EDIT** As usual, @romainl had a cool trick to improve the answer, thanks to him:

```
:g/SPECIAL/,+3d
```

Vimgolfers will like it!

Comment: This command works for  OP's example, but it has problem if there were lines (num<3) between two `SPECI..` lines

Comment: As far as I read the question, it seems that the pattern and the next three lines have to be deleted. I hope that user knows what the file has exactly.

Comment: Yes, I do know the content of my file.

Comment: @Kent: That's a good remark but OP specifically said he need to delete 3 lines. Now a more general solution would need a little more complexity to check the number of lines

Comment: @statox then your answer and also the macro one work well. otherwise both won't work. because macro (search`/ or n`) and `:g//address cmd`  both process sequentially from BOF -> EOF.

Comment: …and shortened to `:g/SPECIAL/,+3d`.

Comment: @romainl you are here on this site too... :-D

Comment: @Kent, yep, [since day one](http://vi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)

Comment: @statox, by the way… did you know http://tuppervim.org/ ?

Comment: @romainl i just discovered it some weeks ago (actually nobe4 told me about it). The concept seemed really cool and I would have loved to meet you IRL, that's why you saw me on the inscription list. Unfortunately I had a last minute appointment imposed by my boss so I couldn't make it... But I definitely want to come next time! Are you the main organizer of the event? (maybe we should continue in the chat)

Comment: @statox, no I only participated a few times. There's no date yet for the next one but you would be very welcome.

Comment: @romainl: Well thanks! I'll keep an eye on the next date :-)

Comment: Vimgolf: `:g/SPECIAL/d4`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vim macro`s!

Edit: As @statox suggested, we can search the pattern first and then record macro. It will avoid searching the same pattern every time.

Search for the pattern `/pattern`.

Press `qaq` to clean the register `a`. 
Press `qa` to start recording. Press `n` to search  the next occurrence of the pattern. Then press `4dd` to delete four lines including that line. Press `@a` to repeat the process. Press `q` to stop recording.

Now onwards, you can press `@a` once. It will search for the pattern and delete four lines. :)

Explanation:

```
           qaq - start recording in `a` register and stop recording. (Indirectly, means that you are clearing register a.
```

Comment: Actually you would need to first search for the pattern `/SPECIAL` then use `n` in the macro `qan4ddq`

Comment: @statox put `/pattern<cr>` in macro is also ok.

Comment: also I would use a nested macro to avoid `999@a` or even `999999@a`

Comment: or use a global command that you apply a macro on?

Comment: @Kent You are right, it is just a matter of preference so I should have phrased my comment differently :-) The nested macro if a good idea here.

Comment: @statox perhaps I played vimgolf too much. `/pat<cr>` will beat `/pat<cr> then n` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Even though you say you want a single command that does it automatically, I would suggest not doing that unless you really have a ton of them. Often attempting to come up with one command that does it all in one go is problematic compared to a simpler approach. You might have to try several commands before you come up with one that really works, whereas with a simpler approach you will probably get it right on your first or second attempt and you can think of what to do much quicker and without asking for help. Also, I often find that while I believe I know exactly how this pattern I want to delete appears every time in the file, there are often slight variances of it I had forgotten about or was not aware of. These variances might get picked up by the single command approach and deleted. You may not have wanted to delete them or it might delete more or less than what you wanted for a particular variance.

It is safer to let yourself see each match and decide to or not to delete it. Here is the approach I would take.

Type the following:
`/\/\/ SPECIAL`

At this point it should be clear that you did or did not enter the search correctly before you ever delete anything, which is one of the advantages of this approach.

Once you verify you searched for the right thing, instead of pressing `4dd`, enter linewise visual mode with a captial `V`. Instead of finding how many lines to go down, which will consume some of your mental visual processing ability for the day, do it the lazy way. Just press `j` a few times until it looks right. That way is much easier to visually process. This also has the advantage of preventing you from mistakenly thinking you needed to delete 4 lines when you actually needed to delete 5 or some other amount, as you can clearly see highlighted what you are about to delete.

Once you have highlighted the lines you want to delete, just press `d` to delete them. You only need to press it once, since you are in linewise visual mode. At this point, you can see that you either did or did not actually want to delete it that way without altering the entire file. It is not uncommon to notice that while you did delete what you intended, it would be better to also delete the line below it, as it is just white space. This is one of the advantages of this approach, you can refine exactly what you want to delete in one place before moving on to the rest of the file. The key here is to make sure that you undo the change that wasn't quite correct, and then delete all of it with a single command so that `.` will work well for you going forward.

Once you have deleted what you want, press `n` to jump to the next search result. Look and see if you really want to delete that next one. To delete it, just press `.` to repeat your last deletion. Keep doing this until they are all deleted. So basically, you are pressing `n.` over and over again.

This way with each result you can visually decide if that match is really the same and if you really want to delete it each time, and then deleting it is as simple as pressing `.`. If you encounter a match where you want to delete it differently, ignore it for now, move onto the next result. Otherwise, you will mess up your `.`. Finish deleting all the places that don't require any changes in how you delete it. Then keep pressing `n` and try some variance of this approach to delete the remaining matches.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time of writing this. I am aware of the possible destruction implied by the global command. But this case is specifically fitted for the "match and delete" workflow. In some more nebulous cases, a one-by-one approach may be better, but I am sure of the content of my file and don't mind taking the shotgun to this.

Comment: @nobe4 Sounds good. At least I have the thought process described here so you and other people can see if this answer applies to them or not. Hopefully it will open up someones mind see a new approach that will help them at some point.

Comment: @stilldreaming. I hope you can answer in a simple way :)

Comment: @SibiCoder For some people more words is simpler ;) I am describing things here in enough detail that someone who is not already familiar with all those concepts can kind of get the idea just from reading this.